# Why doesn't event listener trigger when submit is called?

Tags: javascript, html

Seems like calling `.submit()` on a form ignores added listeners:

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(new FormData(e.target)))
})

document.querySelector('#no-trigger').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('form').submit()
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="example" id="example">
  <button id="trigger">trigger listener</button>
</form>
<button id="no-trigger">don't trigger listener</button>
```

I would expect that clicking `no-trigger` button would also trigger the listener, but it reloads the page instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behavior. From MDN:

> The event is not sent to the form when calling the [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit) method directly.

From [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element:event-submit) (emphasis mine):

> ##### `form.submit()`
>
> Submits the form, bypassing interactive constraint validation and **without firing a submit event.**

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about `requestSubmit` method. Seems unusual because `click` trigger event listeners. I would expect a different naming convention e.g. `forceSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the requestSubmit.
I for some reason have to manually add the submit button to the form data

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formData = new FormData(e.target)
  
  for (var x of formData) console.log(x);
  
  // for some reason it does not capture the named button
  formData.append("edit",e.submitter ? e.submitter.value : undefined) // captures the submitter's value if available
  
  console.log(Object.fromEntries(formData))
})

document.getElementById('triggerEdit').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('form').requestSubmit(document.querySelector('[name=edit]'));
})
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="example" id="example">
  <button id="trigger">trigger listener</button>
  <input type="submit" name="edit" value="trigger listener using this submit button" />
</form>
<hr/>
<button id="triggerEdit">ALSO trigger listener as if the edit button had been clicked</button>
```